# No show my data in TextView Xcoed 8

Tags: database, sqlite, swift3, textview, xcode8

I don't know what's the problem, I connected my SQLite database with Swift 3 and I'm using in my Main Storyboard TextView.
I created 2 classes (DatabaseModel & DatabaseHelper), Database Model is definition rows in database sqlite and DatabaseHelper is some code to connection with my database, when I run my project the simulator is empty why ?!!
Please help me !

```
import UIKit

class MenuViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

        var listDatabase = [DatabaseModel]()
        var dbHelper = DatabaseHelper()
        var data: DatabaseModel?

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

            loadDtabase()

        }


        func loadDtabase() {

            listDatabase = dbHelper.getDatabase()

            do {

                textView.text = data?.ques
                textView.textColor = UIColor.black
                textView.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)

                print("It's do it :)")

            } catch {

                print("NO Data !!!")

            }

        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var TextView: UITextView!

    var dbHelper = DatabaseHelper()
    var listDatabase = [DatabaseModel]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        listDatabase = dbHelper.getDatabase()



        do {

            for data in listDatabase {

                TextView.text = data.ques
                TextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
                TextView.textColor = .green
                TextView.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
                print("Database is succseded connection...")

            }

        } catch {

            print("Get all database fail !!!")

        }


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```